# JQuery Mobile performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My JQM application needs to display only content that never changes. That's why I've written a static website which is about (HTML file <= 500kb).

I am using the multipage architecture. No own JavaScript is used.

The application works well on newer smartphones, but lags on older smartphones. Are there any ways to optimize the performance of JQM?

(Split into different files is not wanted..)

Comment: 500kb of html without any script can bog down old phones... use less.

Comment: Create pages/elements dynamically on request.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case that you're developing your website to make it work with [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mobile/mini) as well, and then you'll have to make your website rely less on JavaScript.

If your website is actually a Mobile Webapp which substitutes a dedicated native app for smartphones that can't run it, you might want to make all your modules AMD-ready so that not all of your code gets downloaded at once.

And since you mention that:

> I've written a static website which is about (HTML file <= 500kb).

I believe loading all that markup is not wise, if your target "old smartphones" have browsers which can handle Ajax, you can load page content selectively and maintain webapp state via hash-tagging the URLs.

Obviously, there's no magic wand to fix the problem your facing except for some modifications that I've suggested. You may want to check Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript) and some tips from [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). :)